# Rings where ideals decompose into product of primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In a Dedekind Domain we have unique decomposition of ideals into product of prime ideals. My question out of curiosity is: Is there a ring satisfying this which is not a Dedekind Domain?

Comment: A domain is Dedekind iff every nonzero proper ideal is a product of prime ideals. Equivalently with maximal ideals. Are you asking about generalizations to rings (vs, domains)?

Answer (score 0):

Something that looks like a Dedekind Domain but is not a domain.

In particular every $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $n$ square-free should work, by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Any integral domain with unique ideal factorization is already a Dedekind domain, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113867/a-sufficient-condition-for-a-domain-to-be-dedekind). For rings with zero divisors, this is not true in general - consider $\mathbb{Z}/6$ for example.

Comment: It would be better to give a specific link to the result that you cite, rather than a generic Google search.

Comment: @BillDubuque a good pointer is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition (noetherian rings) ?

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, of course, I am sorry. Cut and paste went wrong.